# JasperSoft - Refreshing oracle materialized view before executing JasperReport

Tags: java, oracle, jasper-reports, materialized-views

I've created a Jasper Report which uses a materialized view. 
I want to refresh the mv every time before the report is executing to have updated data.
Is there any way to do sth like this in Jasper?
I tried it using java scriptlet, but it doesnt work somehow, report is executing but the mv doesn't refresh.

```
@Override
public void beforeReportInit() throws JRScriptletException {
    try {
        CallableStatement stmt = preparePlSqlCall(
        "DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH('MV_CHECK_GRAFIK_KUNDEN','C')");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}


private Connection conn;

private Connection getConnection() throws JRScriptletException {
    if (conn == null) {
        if (getParameterValue(JRFillParameter.REPORT_CONNECTION) != null) {
            conn = (Connection) (getParameterValue(JRFillParameter.REPORT_CONNECTION));
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("Keine Datenbank-Verbindung am Report konfiguriert");
        }
    }
    return conn;
}

protected CallableStatement preparePlSqlCall(String sql) throws JRScriptletException, SQLException {
    return getConnection().prepareCall("begin " + sql + "; end;");
}
```

Thanks for help guys!

Comment: `I tried it using java scriptlet, but it doesnt work somehow, report is executing but the mv doesn't refresh.` - Are you sure that scriptlet was ran?

Comment: I hope so, i created the scriptlet using the JRAbstractClass and then added it to the Report. Is there any way to check this or do I have to do anything else to run it?

Comment: You can use scriptlet for showing something at textField, for example

Comment: i don't see stmt.execute()  in the beforeReportInit() method. Do you execute refresh ?

Comment: more like this?

public void beforeReportInit() throws JRScriptletException {
  try {

   CallableStatement stmt = preparePlSqlCall(
     "DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH('MV_CHECK_GRAFIK_KUNDEN','C')");

   try {
    stmt.execute();
    } finally {
    stmt.close();
   }
  } catch (SQLException e) {
   throw new RuntimeException("Fehler beim Aufruf von beforeReportInit", e);
  }
 }

Comment: Are you dropping your materilialize view after running report ? If not , try to drop materialize view when report is finished.

Comment: I think that's not the problem, the beforeReportInit() doesn't even execute the dbms_refresh.. And i'd like the report to wait until the refresh is finished, that's another problem..

Comment: @AaronR. you can create procedure and write refresh method in it and call that procedure into your report.

Comment: @FahadAnjum i created a procedure like this: CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE REFRESH_MV_CHECK_KUNDEN_GRAFIK AS 
BEGIN 
DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH('MV_CHECK_GRAFIK_KUNDEN','C');
END;
Then i called it in the report like this: 
public void beforeReportInit() throws JRScriptletException {
  try {

   CallableStatement stmt = preparePlSqlCall(
     "REFRESH_MV_CHECK_KUNDEN_GRAFIK");

   try {
    stmt.execute();
   } finally {
    stmt.close();
   }
  } catch (SQLException e) {
   throw new RuntimeException("Fehler beim Aufruf von beforeReportInit", e);
  }
 }
But that doesn't work either..

Comment: How are you saying it is not working ? could you please create a minimal code and paste it here so that we can see what have you tried.

Comment: @FahadAnjum

`code CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE REFRESH_MV_CHECK_KUNDEN_GRAFIK AS BEGIN DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH('MV_CHECK_GRAFIK_KUNDEN','C'); END;
` 

`code public void beforeReportInit() throws JRScriptletException {
  try {

   CallableStatement stmt = preparePlSqlCall(
     "MV_CHECK_KUNDEN_GRAFIK");

   try {
    stmt.execute();
   } finally {
    stmt.close();
   }
  } catch (SQLException e) {
   throw new RuntimeException("Fehler beim Aufruf von beforeReportInit", e);
  }
 }` 


After that I just executed the report and saw in the DB that the mv didn't refresh.

Comment: Problem solved, just created a normal view instead of mv, execution time differences aren't that big. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @AaronR. Good to hear.